# Is there anyway of represent the name of an Object as a variable?

Tags: object, variables, vb6

I am currently working on creating Chess. I am fairly new to coding and am wondering if I can use an variable to represent the name of a **Command Button**.
ActivePiece is a variable.

```
Dim ActivePiece As String
ActivePiece = "WhitePawn4"

ElseIf ActivePiece = "WhitePawn4" Then
WhitePawn4.Left = Square(Index).Left
WhitePawn4.Top = Square(Index).Top
astrSquare(Index) = "WhitePawn4"
astrSquare(intPreviousSquareNumber) = ""
```

Since chess has 32 pieces using this method I would have to use 32 if statements. I have tried using a varible:

```
ActivePiece.Left = Square(Index).Left
ActivePiece.Top = Square(Index).Top
astrSquare(Index) = ActivePiece
astrSquare(intPreviousSquareNumber) = ""
```

But it doesn't seem to work since it looks for a command button named **Active Piece**. Is there anyway to tell the computer that **Active Piece** represent a variable and it should use the string as the name of the Command Button?

I have tried Using `Me.ActivePiece` But nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: I'm guessing ActivePiece is a command button?  If so, then ActivePiece.Name I think is what you're wanting

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, ActivePiece is a variable. I would want the string assigned to the variable to be used as the name of the Command Button.

Comment: Where does the Command button come from, is that something you're creating at runtime or design time?  If runtime simply set the name property as required, if design time, just name it in the form designer properties.  Also worth pointing out, you can use the Form.Controls collection to find the button you're after (either iterate or Linq query) which may save the need for doing 32 if statements

Comment: The Command Button is created during design time. I'm unsure what you mean when saying that I can use Form.Controls collection.

Comment: The button itself in a way can be thought of a variable that is added to the Forms.Contols collection during construction of the form at runtime.  You can query that collection to find instances of particular controls. Have a readup on it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.controlcollection?view=net-5.0

Comment: This is not VB6. There are no "command buttons". It's a `Button`. The class is `System.Windows.Forms.Button`.

Comment: As for the question, why store the name when you can store the `Button` itself? Declare `ActivePiece` as type `Button` and then assign the appropriate `Button` when and how you want, then use it when and how you want. You can get or set any properties of that `Button` object, including the `Name`, via the `ActivePiece` variable.

Comment: Please change the tag of your question from VB6 to vb.net. The two languages are different!